# Формат изображения BMI

Tags: bmp

[image: Столкнулся с необходимостью создавать или экспортировать изображения в формат BMI. Поиски в интернетах говорят, что это Zoner Bitmaps BMI. Инструментов для экспорта-создания не нашел. Судя по всему изображение рисуется цветовыми зонами. На скриншоте размер картинки 26х29.]

Столкнулся с необходимостью создавать или экспортировать изображения в формат BMI. Поиски в интернетах говорят, что это Zoner Bitmaps BMI. Инструментов для экспорта-создания не нашел. Судя по всему изображение рисуется цветовыми зонами. На скриншоте размер картинки 26х29.

HEX-дамп

```
42 4D B2 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 3E 00 00 00 28 00 00 00 1A 00 00 00 1D 00
00 00 01 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 74 00 00 00 C3 0E 00 00 C3 0E 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF FF FF 00 FF FF FF C0 FF FF FF C0 FF FF
FF C0 E0 00 0F C0 E0 00 0F C0 F0 00 0F C0 F0 00 0F C0 F0 00 0F C0 F8 0F
FF C0 FC 07 FF C0 FE 03 FF C0 FF 01 FF C0 FF 80 7F C0 FF C0 3F C0 FF E0
1F C0 FF F0 1F C0 FF F8 0F C0 FF FC 0F C0 E0 7C 0F C0 E0 7C 0F C0 E0 38
0F C0 F0 00 1F C0 F0 00 1F C0 F8 00 3F C0 FE 00 FF C0 FF FF FF C0 FF FF
FF C0 FF FF FF C0 FF FF FF C0
```

Кто-то сталкивался с таким? Какие инструменты для экспорта из BMP, PNG форматов посоветуете или редактор с возможностью сохранения в этом формате?

Comment: Вопрос: "как сконвертировать bmp, png картинки в bmi" (в не зависимости от языка, ОСи, итд)?

Comment: Да, есть возможность доступа к любой ОС. Методом тыка через mogrify определил, что это BMP3

Comment: В общем, сам задал, сам решил )) Это формат BMP3, imagemagic (mogrify, convert) позволяет в него экспортировать. Спасибо за отклики.

Comment: вместо комментария, лучше добавить ответ (и принять его через пару дней) -- может другим пригодится.

Comment: Спасибо........

Answer (score 2):

Это формат BMP3, imagemagic (mogrify, convert) позволяет в него экспортировать